# Create EOS Account using c#

Tags: accounts, account-creation

How can I create an eos account in c#. I have generated the eos public and private keys using c#. Now i want to create an eos account in c# using the generated public key. Can someone guide me how to create it?

Comment: Could you share a repository where you generate the keys with C#?

Comment: same question here.

Comment: Could you share a repository where you generate the keys with C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EosSharp](https://github.com/GetScatter/eos-sharp) or [ScatterSharp](https://github.com/GetScatter/scatter-sharp) (includes EosSharp). In both cases, if you want to create a new account the common way, the transaction would look like this:

```
        string newAcc = "mynewaccount";

        var result = await eos.CreateTransaction(new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Transaction()
        {
            actions = new List<EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action>()
            {
                new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action()
                {
                    account = "eosio.system",
                    authorization = new List<PermissionLevel>()
                    {
                        new PermissionLevel() {actor = account.name, permission = account.authority}
                    },
                    name = "newaccount",
                    data = new { creator = account.name, name = newAcc, owner = "EOSMYPUBLICKEYABC345AJJD...", active = "EOSMYPUBLICKEYABC345AJJD..." }
                },
                new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action()
                {
                    account = "eosio.system",
                    authorization = new List<PermissionLevel>()
                    {
                        new PermissionLevel() {actor = account.name, permission = account.authority}
                    },
                    name = "buyrambytes",
                    data = new { creator = account.name, name = newAcc, bytes = 1024}
                },
                new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action()
                {
                    account = "eosio.system",
                    authorization = new List<PermissionLevel>()
                    {
                        new PermissionLevel() {actor = account.name, permission = account.authority}
                    },
                    name = "delegatebw",
                    data = new { creator = account.name, name = newAcc, stake_net_quantity = 0.100, stake_cpu_quantity = 0.100, transfer = false}
                }
            }
    });
```

You can find more information about the different system-conract-actions here [eosio.system](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.cpp)